# Association not imported in EF4 designer for non-primary key

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

**The relationship 'FK_EXTERNAL_ISMARKETI_MARKETIN' has columns that are not part of the key of the table on the primary side of the relationship. The relationship was excluded.**

USE [Instruments.UnitTest]
    GO

```
ALTER TABLE [Instr].[ExternalIdentification]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EXTERNAL_ISMARKETI_MARKETIN] FOREIGN KEY([InstrumentID], [MarketInstrumentID])
REFERENCES [Instr].[MarketInstrument] ([InstrumentID], [MarketInstrumentID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Instr].[ExternalIdentification] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EXTERNAL_ISMARKETI_MARKETIN]
GO
```

I'm using an association for **NON-PRIMARY KEY** columns, is this possible in the EF4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such associations are not supported in EF v4.

Comment: Any MS documentation that prove that statement sir?

Comment: In EF v1 there was no support, take a look at this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/654d4e35-eed9-4554-a75e-186b4aff7515
As for EF v4, we have tried to make such associations to work and have not succeeded - mapping error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Its explained in more detail in this post here

http://www.cognitiveinheritance.com/post/Using-the-Entity-Framework-with-databases-that-have-foreign-key-relationships-that-do-not-link-to-the-primary-key-of-the-child-element.aspx